# Extracting text from a list BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, list, text, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and webscraping.

I'm trying to extract the text from a list that starts with `"a href"`.

The whole list is in a variable named `team"`.
If I write `team[0].a.text` I get the first text.
But when I do `team[0:14].a.text` I get this response:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'a'`
```

I guess that means that the a.text function doesn't work on a list.

How can get a list from of text from this?

Here is a sample of the code as requested:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://ligueelite.hockey-richelieu.qc.ca/fr/stats/classement.html?season=2295&subSeason=2296&category=2134'

#opening connection and grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
# html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# grab each team
team = page_soup.findAll("td",{"class":"team"})
```

Comment: Welcome Charles, can you add a part of your current code to give us some more informations?

Comment: `team[0:14]` is a list, so you'll have to loop over it to get the `a.text` for each element in said list.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thank you for your comment. That's what I figured too but I just don't know yet how to properly write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correctly you need to use loop.

for example:

```
text_links_array = []
for i in team:
  text_links_array.append(i.a.text)
print(text_links_array)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What exactly would I write in print() to see if it works.

Comment: `print(text_links_array)`

Comment: It works! thanks so much. I learned a lot from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
texts = []
for t in team:
    texts.append(t.select_one('a').get_text(strip=True))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What exactly would I write in print() to see if it works.

Comment: print(texts) @Charles